# once we navigate from one activity to other .where can define elements for new activity since there is only one main.xml

Tags: android

hi im new to android i have added defined login screen in one screen or activity im now navigating to next activity where i have to place elements for user to enter there details ..but where to place these elements since there is only one main.xml..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another XML in Layout folder.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.newLayout);`

Comment: @bharath - if this answered your question you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.